# HTML5 .MP4 video not playing

Tags: php, html, video, html5-video

I converted a video to a **base64string** and decoded the base64string and used file_put_contents to convert it into a mp4 file. I did this so that I can get the video from my mobile app to my server. There is no problem with that I can convert and create the file and play the video in VLC however, the problem is when I put the path file of the converted video inside the VIDEO tag the video wont play and when I put a MP4 video downloaded from YouTube it is working. I don't know why the video wont play.

Base64String to MP4 Conversion:

```
$video_decode = base64_decode($Video);
$video_filename = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/TBSApp/uploads/'. $CAF . '_'.$CafDate.'_VID.mp4';
$video_dbfilename = './uploads/'. $CAF . '_'.$CafDate.'_VID.mp4';
$save_video = file_put_contents($video_filename, $video_decode);
```

HTML video:

```
<div class="act-image-container">
    <video class="act-img" controls>
       <source src="'.$row["Video"].'" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Path:

> ./uploads/VQ4475WWUK_2018-10-11_VID.mp4

Comment: try using [videojs](https://videojs.com/) to play video in html

Comment: still not working @Ascaliko

Comment: have you try it ?, what the error show when  you use videojs

Comment: @Ascaliko I getting not supported error

Comment: what the value of `$row["Video"]` ?, please more the detail of code above

Comment: @Ascaliko ./uploads/VQ4475WWUK_2018-10-11_VID.mp4

Comment: what the file exist in there

Comment: @Ascaliko video and photo

Comment: what the error like [this](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/3726) and [this](https://gist.github.com/chrisroos/11256392)
can you update question and add complete code

Comment: Make a small example video file that does not work in `<video>`tag. Post the converted video link here for analysis.

Comment: @VC.One try to convert a video to base64string then decode it and make it a file like my code above and try to put it in video tag it will not work i dont know why

Comment: Does it work if you use the full correct path (not beginning with just `./`), example: `src="https://www.example.com/uploads/VQ4475WWUK_2018-10-11_VID.mp4`?  PS: I would never convert a video to base64, but if you have one, 
 then I'll check that data is still remains correct. You get correct playback in VLC either because file is okay or VLC is fixing a problem(s) in the background.

Comment: @VC.One its not working

Comment: Save this example [small.mp4](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4) and then convert that to base64 and provide a link to converted file, Do you have any online storage account like Google Drive or DropBox? Or just make a link on your own website server. Share the converted problem file for analysis since it's not clear what went wrong **with your conversion**. For example (if file is MP4) does your B64 string start with `MDAwMDAw` or does it start with `AAAAHGZ0eXBtc`?

Comment: Either your B64 conversion is wrong or your `src="'.$row["Video"].'"` is wrong. However since you say that the converted file cannot play in a [basic video tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) using the full direct link (no PHP or DB variables involved, only file path), I think then the video bytes are messed up. Only you can see them so I suggest you get a free Hex editor and compare working bytes (before B64) vs not working bytes (after B64).